# DevExpress TreeList hanging on expand

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, devexpress-mvc

So my tree loads and looks just fine and I can get it to workish. When I click on the expand button, the children load just fine, but the loading box doesn't go away. But if I click the check boxes next to the expand button it makes the loading box go away and I can then expand or minimize once more. But again when I click the expand it hangs up until I check and uncheck one of those boxes again. Can anyone point me towards what could be causing this. I don't know if maybe its just a setting or maybe I need to load my Data dynamically or something. If someone could just point me in the right direction I would be grateful.

I found out that I am getting an error now, but I have to head home for the day. Ill post the error and maybe that will help you guys help me.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefinedVM105:346
delegateVM105:1240 (anonymous function)VM93:5109      
jQuery.event.dispatchVM93:4780 elemData.handleVM93:5021 
jQuery.event.triggerVM93:5344 jQuery.event.simulateVM93:5595 
handlerVM138:742 _aspxSetInnerHtmlVM138:8958 
_aspxCreateClass.ProcessFullCallbackResultVM138:8925 
_aspxCreateClass.ProcessCallbackResultVM138:11431 
_aspxCreateClass.ProcessCallbackResultVM138:8767 
_aspxCreateClass.OnCallbackVM138:5213 
_aspxCreateClass.ProcessCallbackVM138:5198 
_aspxCreateClass.DoCallbackVM138:10647 $.ajax.successVM140:3062 
jQuery.Callbacks.fireVM140:3174 jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWithVM140:8249 
doneVM140:8792 jQuery.ajaxTransport.send.callback
```